# Spring-MVC @ModelAttribute and @Autowired

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to initialize an Object with the @ModelAttribute Annontation on a Method. When calling the URL "/p/PPP/scope" strange things happen. The ProjectService seems not to be instantiated when calling the @ModelAttribute method, but it is there when calling the show() method. Has anybody an idea whats wrong in this?

Here are the log statements:

```
12:32:19 [DEBUG] ScopeController - getProject() - loading project for 'PPP'
12:32:19 [DEBUG] ScopeController - getProject() - projectService initialized? null
12:32:21 [DEBUG] ScopeController - show() - projectService initialized? ...project.ProjectService@20f2442e
```

and the source:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/p/{abbr}/scope")
@SessionAttributes("project")
public class ScopeController {

    public static final String SHOW_PROJECT_PAGE = "/projects/scope/show";

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ScopeController.class);

    @Autowired
    private ProjectService projectService;

    @ModelAttribute("project")
    private Project getProject(@PathVariable(value = "abbr") String abbr) {
        log.debug("getProject() - loading project for '{}'", abbr);
        log.debug("getProject() - projectService initialized? {}", projectService);
        // should call this method:
        // return projectService.find(abbr);
        return new Project();
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @Transactional
    public String show() throws BindException {
        log.debug("show() - projectService initialized? {}", projectService);
        return SHOW_PROJECT_PAGE;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after playing around I found the solution. The problem was the name in the @ModelAttribute. After removing the "project" the method works as expectet. Because of the confusion regarding the "getProject()"-method, I did a little refactoring to make the intention of the method more clear. Here is the complete class with additional comments:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/p/{abbr}/scope")
public class ScopeController {

    private static final String SHOW_PROJECT_PAGE = "/projects/scope/show";

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ScopeController.class);

    @Autowired
    private ProjectService projectService;

    // method is called before show() and update()
    @ModelAttribute
    private void initProject(@PathVariable(value = "abbr") String abbr, Model model) {
        log.debug("loading project for '{}'", abbr);
        // load the project JPA entity from the database, will be merged with the  
        // updated form values in the POST request. By doing this, I can asure
        // that the primary key (the ID) and the related objects are present as 
        // needed for the em.saveOrUpdate() in the projectService.save() method.
        model.addAttribute("project", projectService.find(abbr));
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String show() throws BindException {
        // shows the project scope form with the project 
        // added in 'initProject()'
        return SHOW_PROJECT_PAGE;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String update(
            // the project with the updated form values and the JPA ID and JPA 
            // relations as loaded in the initProject()
            @Valid @ModelAttribute Project project, BindingResult result, 
            RedirectAttributes redirectAttrs)
            throws MethodArgumentNotValidException {

        redirectAttrs.addFlashAttribute(project);

        try {
            if (!result.hasErrors()) {
                projectService.save(project);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(e.toString());
            throw new MethodArgumentNotValidException(null, result);
        }

        log.debug("project '{}' updated", project.getAbbreviation());
        return SHOW_PROJECT_PAGE;
    }
}
```

Thanks all for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

**All methods with ModelAttibute annotation must be be public.**

So when method getProject is public - it will work properly:

```
 @ModelAttribute("project")
 public Project getProject( ...
```

Comment: That is true indeed, but any elaboration why? private method works for me, but `@Autowired` fields are null in such situation. Making it public makes them available again. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try a few things.

1. Change the signature of:

   - private Project getProject to
   - **public @ResponseBody** Project
2. Remove @Transactional from controller and move them to whatever service methods need them. (arguably better design practice - doubt it is causing you the problem you describe)
3. Move @ModelAttribute("Project") annotation to the Project class

   - i.e.
     @ModelAttribute("Project")
     public Project get Project(){
     return new Project();
     }

So it would look something like:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/p/{abbr}/scope")
@SessionAttributes("project")
public class ScopeController {

public static final String SHOW_PROJECT_PAGE = "/projects/scope/show";

private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ScopeController.class);

@Autowired
private ProjectService projectService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/<yourUri for getProject>", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Project get(@PathVariable(value = "abbr") String abbr) {
    return getProject(abbr);
}

private Project getProject(String abbr) {
    log.debug("getProject() - loading project for '{}'", abbr);
    log.debug("getProject() - projectService initialized? {}", projectService);
    // should call this method:
    // return projectService.find(abbr);
    return new Project();
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
@Transactional
public String show() throws BindException {
    log.debug("show() - projectService initialized? {}", projectService);
    return SHOW_PROJECT_PAGE;
}
```

}

```
//In your Project class 
@ModelAttribute("project")
public class Project {
//your class stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but all suggestet solutions don't solve the problem: 1: I'm trying to add something to the Model which will be used in other methods in the controller too (though they are not shown in the example), I don't want a ResponseBody. 2. If you have a transaction which spans multiple service calls, the annotation is at the right place (and is not causing the problem) 3. Renaming the ModelAttribute doesn't have an effect on the initialisation of the autowired objects.

Comment: 1. if i understand correctly, you are trying to use a controller action also as a private method for other controller actions? Why not just abstract that logic into a non-controller action method. (edited answer to reflect what i mean)
2. Ok fair enough
3. Not rename, but only use ModelAttribute annotation for Project class, not the getProject method

Comment: Beause I can't answer my own question (to new here), the solution as a comment: So after playing around I found the solution. The problem was the name in the ModelAttribute. After removing the "project" the method works as expectet:

    @ModelAttribute
    private void initProject(@PathVariable(value = "abbr") String abbr, Model model) {
        log.debug("loading project for '{}'", abbr);
        log.debug("projectService initialized? {}", projectService);
        model.addAttribute("project", projectService.find(abbr));
    } 

Thanks all for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, I would put the `@Transactional` annotation in the Repository/data access layer as that is the norm of good layered Spring MVC-annotation based applications. In addition, your `@PathVariable` annotation is used to retrieve values passed in the URI after the controller's base URI. So having this annotation in a private helper method that does not intercept a URI pattern makes little sense.